# JBoss 7.1.1 startup throws exception

Tags: jboss7.x

I have a mobile application which developed using jquery mobile and spring 3.1.

I am trying to run this application in JBOSS 7.1.1 it is throwing the following exception....

```
[org.hdiv.listener.InitListener] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) HDIV's session created:5+l+MTztPhpn4MXhC5v4SJJY.undefined
19:37:17,292 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/mobee].[jsp]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTLDLocation(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:250) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:152) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:386) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:448) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1398) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:130) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:255) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:103) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:194) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:360) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:607) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:312) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:167) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259) [spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at com.manam.mobee.channel.security.MobeeDeviceResolverFilter.doFilterInternal(MobeeDeviceResolverFilter.java:71) [classes:]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_37]
```

but it is running gud in tomcat 7 and jboss5, Please help me ....

thanks & regards.

Answer (score 0):

Since Jboss 7 has a complete different design, you have to modify your project to make it deploy-able on it.

Take some time to read

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Developer+Guide

There's a part about migrating projects from lower versions